# Can I pass constructor parameters to Unity's Resolve() method?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

I am using Microsoft's Unity for dependency injection and I want to do something like this:

```
IDataContext context = _unityContainer.Resolve<IDataContext>();
var repositoryA = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(context); //Same instance of context
var repositoryB = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryB>(context); //Same instance of context

IDataContext context2 = _unityContainer.Resolve<IDataContext>(); //New instance
var repositoryA2 = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(context2);
```

`RepositoryA` and `RepositoryB` both have a constructor that takes an `IDataContext` parameter, and I want Unity to initialize the repository with the context that I pass it. Also note that `IDataContext` is not registered with Unity (I don't want 3 instances of `IDataContext`).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As of today they have added this functionality:

It’s in the latest drop here:

http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33899

Discussion on it here:

http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=66434

Example:

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>(new ParameterOverrides<Foo> { { "name", "bar" }, { "address", 42 } });"
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813322/unity-2-0-how-to-use-resolve-with-resolveroverride

Comment: the link http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33899 is not active

Comment: "Class 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ParameterOverrides' does not have type parameters". I'm using Unity 3.5; is this code valid only for an older version of Unity?

Comment: It works for me.
Note: Your class must have a parametrized constructor with "name" parameter and "address" parameter.

`Foo(string name, int address) { ... } `

Comment: Using Unity 2.1:

`container.Resolve<IFoo>(new ParameterOverrides { { "name", "bar" }, { "address", 42 } });`

Comment: The links are broken now.

Answer (score 39):

< 2 cents>

What if you later on decide to use a different service that requires more or less than just the context?

The problem with constructor parameters and IoC is that the parameters are ultimately tied to the concrete type being used, as opposed to being part of the contract that the service interface defines.

My suggestion would be that you either resolve the context as well, and I believe Unity should have a way for you to avoid constructing 3 instances of it, or you should consider a factory service that has a way for you to construct the object.

For instance, what if you later on decide to construct a repository that doesn't rely on a traditional database at all, but instead use an XML file to produce dummy-data for the test? How would you go about feeding the XML content to that constructor?

IoC is based around decoupling code, by tying in the type and semantics of the arguments to the concrete types, you really haven't done the decoupling correctly, there's still a dependency.

"This code can talk to any type of repository possibly, as long as it implements this interface.... Oh, and uses a data context".

Now, I know that other IoC containers have support for this, and I had it in my first version of my own as well, but in my opinion, it doesn't belong with the resolution step.

< /2 cents>

Comment: I see your point and agree with you, however I still need the RepositoryA and RepositoryB's instances to have the same IDataContext, which needs to be different than RepositoryC.  Also note that IRepositoryA and IRepositoryB has a property for IDataContext.  I'll update the sample code a bit.

Comment: Great point. I was about to add a string parameter to the constructor, but after viewing this point, i decided to make it a full blown object. It only consists of the string at this point, but i can already see how I could add more useful properties to it

Answer (score 11):

Thanks guys ... mine is similar to the post by "Exist". See below:

```
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        _activeDirectoryService = container.Resolve<IActiveDirectoryService>(new ResolverOverride[]
        {
            new ParameterOverride("activeDirectoryServer", "xyz.adserver.com")
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use InjectionConstructor / InjectionProperty / InjectionMethod depending on your Injection Architecture within the ResolvedParameter< T >("name") to get a instance of a pre-registered Object in the container.

In your case this Object must be registered with a Name, and for the same insance you need ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager() as the LifeTimeManager.

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataContext,DataContextA>("DataContextA", new ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager());
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IDataContext,DataContextB>("DataContextB");

  var repositoryA = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(new InjectionConstructor(
new ResolvedParameter<IDataContext>("DataContextA")));

  var repositoryB = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryB>(new InjectionConstructor(
new ResolvedParameter<IDataContext>("DataContextA")));

  var repositoryA2 = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(new InjectionConstructor(
new ResolvedParameter<IDataContext>("DataContextB")));
```

Comment: Are you sure about this code? It doesn't compile... `Resolve` takes a collection of `ResolverOverride`, and `InjectionConstructor` isn't a `ResolverOverride`.

Comment: Yup It looks wrong. Although unity should have designed it that way. If parameter name changes everything breaks

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is: no. Unity currently has no way to pass parameters into the constructor that aren't constant or injected, that I have been able to find. IMHO that's the single biggest thing it's missing, but I think it is by design rather than by omission.

As Jeff Fritz notes, you could in theory create a custom lifetime manager that knows which context instance to inject into various types, but that's a level of hard-coding which seems to obviate the purpose of using Unity or DI in the first place.

You could take a small step back from full DI and make your repository implementations responsible for establishing their own data contexts. The context *instance* can still be resolved from the container but the logic for deciding which one to use would have to go into the implementation of the repository. It's not as pure, certainly, but it would get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative you could use (don't really know if it is a good practice or not) is creating two containers and registering an instance for each:

```
IDataContext context = _unityContainer.Resolve<IDataContext>();
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance(context);
var repositoryA = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(); //Same instance of context
var repositoryB = _unityContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryB>(); //Same instance of context


//declare _unityContainer2
IDataContext context2 = _unityContainer2.Resolve<IDataContext>(); //New instance
_unityContainer2.RegisterInstance(context2);
var repositoryA2 = _unityContainer2.Resolve<IRepositoryA>(context2); //will retrieve the other instance
```

hope this helps too

Answer (score 0):

NotDan, I think you may have answered your own question in comments to lassevk.

First, I would use a LifetimeManager to manage the lifecycle and number of instances of IDataContext that Unity creates.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440953.aspx

It sounds like the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` object will give you the instance management that you need.  With that LifetimeManager in place, Unity should add the same instance of the IDataContext to all objects that require an IDataContext dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 15 years later I was still looking for a definitive answer on how to `Resolve` a class which requires a string to be passed into the constructor.

I found that definitive answer in the UnityContainter.org [docs here in the quickstart info](http://unitycontainer.org/articles/quickstart.html).

Here's the explanation of how Unity picks a particular Constructor when the constructor is overloaded.

> It will create any type with accessible constructor. Consider
> following example:

```
// Simple class Foo
public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(object obj) { }

    public Foo(string id, object obj) { }
}

// Create container
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// Resolve Foo
var value = container.Resolve<Foo>();

// value created with constructor 'Foo(object obj)'
```

> Foo is a simple class with three public constructors. When
> Resolve() is called, **Unity will evaluate available constructors
> and select one with longest list of parameters it can satisfy with
> dependencies**. It will create all required dependencies and pass them
> to selected constructor during initialization.
>
> **In this particular case Unity will select second constructor with
> parameter obj of type Object. Although constructor Foo(string id,
> object obj) is longer, it has parameter of type String which is a
> primitive type. Unity can not create primitive types by itself.** If you
> want to make these available for dependency injection you would need
> to register them with the container. For Unity to select third
> constructor Foo(string id, object obj) you need to register string
> instance with container:

```
// Register string instance
container.RegisterInstance("xyz");

// Resolve Foo
var value = container.Resolve<Foo>();

// value created with constructor 'Foo(string id, object obj)'
```