# How to send a parameter to an object's constructor with Unity's Resolve<>() method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, cag

Using Unity in Prism, I would like to send a parameter to the object's constructor like this:

```
PSEUDO-CODE:

SmartFormPresenter smartFormPresenter1 =
    this.container.Resolve<SmartFormPresenter(customer)>();
```

But instead I have to instatiate it and then assign a property:

```
SmartFormPresenter smartFormPresenter1 =
    this.container.Resolve<SmartFormPresenter>();
smartFormPresenter1.ObjectBeingEdited = customer;
```

**Is there any way to send a parameter to the constructor directly?**

Comment: Did you get a resolution on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a related question that answers this pretty well:
[Can I pass constructor parameters to Unity's Resolve() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787001/can-i-pass-constructor-parameters-to-unitys-resolve-method)

The only option you have if you want to do this is a scoped container.

```
IUnityContainer subContainer = this.container.CreateScopedContainer();
subContainer.RegisterInstance<Customer>(customer);
smartFormPresenter1 = subContainer.Resolve<SmartFormPresenter>();
```