# How can I pass a string value as a parameter when calling GlobalContainer.Resolve in Spring4D?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring4d

When using Spring4D, how can I pass a string value as a parameter when calling GlobalContainer. Resolve so that this string value is used on the resolved class constructor?

I want to resolve a class IWorker that is mapped to a TWorker. The TWorker class has a dependency in it's constructor to an ITool plus a string for the worker's name.

I would guess the answer lies in the array of TValue that can be given as a parameter to GlobalContainer.Resolve but I do not understand how to use it.

I found this post about using a [TParameterOverride](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720440) as a parameter when calling GlobalContainer.Resolve that might have worked but this functionality seems to have disappeared in the 1.1 version of Spring4D.

I want to avoid a call to InjectConstructor when registering my type.

The part where I need help is

```
GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([{what do I put here?}]).Work;
```

Here is my a small project

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Spring.Container;

type
   IWorker = interface
   ['{2BBD7E9C-4806-4F01-9B05-9E9DD928D21D}']
      procedure Work;
   end;

   ITool = interface
   ['{F962209D-4BC3-41C4-9089-0A874632ED1A}']
      procedure Use;
   end;

   TWorker = class(TInterfacedObject, IWorker)
   private
      FTool: ITool;
      FName: string;
      procedure Work;
   public
      constructor Create(tool: ITool; name: string);
   end;

   THammer = class(TInterfacedObject, ITool)
   private
      procedure Use;
   end;

{ TWorker }
constructor TWorker.Create(tool: ITool; name: string);
begin
   FTool := tool;
   FName := name;
end;

procedure TWorker.Work;
begin
   Writeln(FName + ' is working');
   FTool.Use;
end;


{ THammer }
procedure THammer.Use;
begin
   Writeln('Using a hammer');
end;


begin
   try
      GlobalContainer.RegisterType<ITool, THammer>;
      GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IWorker, TWorker>; // TWorker constructor = Create(tool: ITool; name: string);
      GlobalContainer.Build;

      GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([{what do I put here?}]).Work;
      GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>(['THammer.Create', 'Bob']).Work; //--> 'Unsatisfied constructor on type: TWorker'
      GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([THammer.Create, 'Bob']).Work; //--> Access violation
      GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([nil, 'Bob']).Work; //--> 'Unsatisfied constructor on type: TWorker'
      Readln;
   except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
         Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
         Readln;
      end;
   end;
end.
```

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sam said you should avoid using the container as service locator throughout your code as that is just a replacement of a constructor call to a call to the container which leads to even worse code than everything hardwired.

While it *is* possible to pass arguments to the Resolve call it really should be solved by using factories.

This would be how to pass a value for the name argument (the tool is injected by the container since it knows about that (`TNamedValue` is declared in `Spring.pas`).

```
GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([TNamedValue.Create('name', 'Bob')]).Work;
```

But we can combine that code with registering a factory (unfortunately because the RTTI is lacking information about a type being an anonymous method type we have to use `TFunc<...>`)

```
type
  TWorkerFactory = TFunc<string, IWorker>;

...

GlobalContainer.RegisterType<ITool, THammer>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IWorker, TWorker>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterInstance<TWorkerFactory>(
  function (name: string): IWorker
  begin
    Result := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IWorker>([TNamedValue.Create('name', name)]);
  end);
GlobalContainer.Build;

GlobalContainer.Resolve<TWorkerFactory>.Invoke('Bob').Work;
```

So this enables you putting a `TWorkerFactory` argument somewhere in your code where the container then can inject it. That way you have decoupled code using dependency injection but without any direct dependency on the container (in fact you could still wire up everything manually which is the rule as I stated previously)

With the 1.2 release the container will support automatic factory creation so you can write code like this:

```
type
  {$M+}
  TWorkerFactory = reference to function(const name: string): IWorker;

...

GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<TWorkerFactory>;
```

This automatically creates a proxy that passes the arguments of the factory method further into the container.

Comment: Stefan can you share an example to us? 
How can TWorkerFactory can be wired?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this is to register a factory for the worker in the container and then ask the factory to return a worker using a specific tool and string (Name?).

your current code looks like it might be expecting to use the container inside the application, which is a smell as the container should only be used in the [Composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) really

Answer (score 1):

I understand this should be avoided but I found out a way to call resolve with my string parameter.

The following code works but is a bad idea:

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<ITool, THammer>;
  GlobalContainer.RegisterInstance<TFunc<string, IWorker>>(
     function(workerName: string): IWorker
     begin
           Result := TWorker.Create(GlobalContainer.Resolve<ITool>, workerName);
     end);
  GlobalContainer.Build;

  GlobalContainer.Resolve<TFunc<string, IWorker>>.Invoke('Bob').Work;
```