# Unity Framework - passing integer's and strings into resolved objects

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

is there a way using the Unity framework to pass an integer as an argument into the constructor or a resolved object?

Pseudo code..

```
IService svc = Container.Resolve<ConcreteService>()
```

in this case Concrete service will be something like this...

```
public class ConcreteService
{
    public ConcreteService(int val)
    {
    }
}
```

Also I need to do this in xml configuration as opposed to doing it in code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Can I pass constructor parameters to Unity’s Resolve() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787001/can-i-pass-constructor-parameters-to-unitys-resolve-method)

Comment: That question is about passing in an object, which I think that unity will detect this and create appropriate objects to pass in. I want to pass in a value type which is slightly different.

Comment: No. Have a look at the second link in the accepted answer. This describes how *any* arguments can be passed to a constructor for a certain type. In your example, you would have to use it like this: `Container.Resolve<IService>(new ParameterOverrides<ConcreteService> { { "val" }, { 42 } });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope I understood you right

```
   public class ConcreteService {

        public int Val { get; set; }

        public ConcreteService(int val) {
            Val = val;
        }
    }
```

Now let's configure unity.

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ConcreteService>();
        container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<ConcreteService>(new InjectionConstructor(1));

        container.RegisterType<ConcreteService>("for42");
        container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<ConcreteService>("for42",
                                                                                      new InjectionConstructor(42));
        container.RegisterType<ConcreteService>("for31");
        container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<ConcreteService>("for31",
                                                                                      new InjectionConstructor(31));

        Debug.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ConcreteService>().Val); //1
        Debug.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ConcreteService>("for42").Val); //42
        Debug.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ConcreteService>("for31").Val); //31
```

Equvivalent configuration for "for42" is

### Unity 1.4

```
<type type="ConcreteService"  name="for42">
          <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement,
                                     Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
            <constructor>
              <param name="val" parameterType="int">
                <value value="42"/>
              </param>
            </constructor>           
          </typeConfig>
        </type>
```

### Unity 2.0

It's much the same but without redundant typeConfig  node

```
<type type="ConcreteService"  name="for42">
        <constructor>
              <param name="val" parameterType="int">
                <value value="42"/>
              </param>
            </constructor>           
        </type>
```