# Passing List of Strings or Array of strings into Unity Injection Constructor (Config-Based)

Tags: c#, xml, dependency-injection, unity-container

I cannot seem to get unity working when attempting to pass in an array of strings into a constructor parameter list, while using XML configuration.

When I try the following:

```
<typeConfig ...>
  <constructor ...>
    <param ... parameterType="System.String[]">
     <array>    
      <value.../>
      <value.../>
     </array>
    </param> 
  </constructor>
</typeConfig>
```

for a c'tor which looks like this:

```
void Foo(string[] inputParams_){ ... }
```

It always fails in Unity's FindConstructor(...) method stating that it cannot find a c'tor mathcing the parameter type of String.String

Does anyone know how to pass an array of stings successfully into this type of c'tor?  If not, how can I do so with a list of strings, if the c'tor were to accept an IList?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the attribute 'parameterType' for the element 'param'

This will work:

```
    <constructor>
      <param name="eventsDefinitions">
        <array>
          <value value="PhaseLoss"/>
          <value value="DCRC" />
          <value value="PhaseRotation" />
        </array>
      </param>
    </constructor>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically I prefer to configure Unity in code, so I may not be that helpful if config is a must. But ....

Typically I'd use a
 ConstructorInjector during registration:

> container.Configure()
>       .ConfigureInjectionFor(new InjectionConstructor([*value*]))

But according to:
[Can I pass constructor parameters to Unity's Resolve() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787001/can-i-pass-constructor-parameters-to-unitys-resolve-method)

Unity 2 should now also includes the ability to pass parameters into the constructor dynamically during resolution:

> "container.Resolve(new
>   ParameterOverrides { { "name",
>   "bar" }, { "address", 42 } });"

Comment: thanks, but the questions is *specifically* about configuratin files

Comment: No worries. Another worthless try is - I've seen the notation "'1" dotted around text configuration, something like "String'1" usually when referring to some sort of generic collection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have to fully qualify the type name:

```
System.String[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Optionally, you may drop the version if you don't care/know.

Comment: hmm, not sure will try it, but system.string doesnt require qualification elsewhere.