# Unity 2.0: How to use Resolve with ResolverOverride?

Tags: .net, unity2.0

I started doing more and more work with [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).  I notice that Resolver method takes a *params* argument *ResolverOverride*.

Can someone give me an example how I can use *ResolverOverride* or point me some other source where I can get more clues.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As you have noticed this is a new (and really cool feature) of the Unity 2. This feature let you

- pass parameters to constructor in the moment when you resolve the class. In unity 1 you can set only one value in the moment when you register type via new InjectionConstructor(...)

There is `ParameterOverride : ResolverOverride`

> A ResolverOverride class that lets you
>   override a named parameter passed to a
>   constructor.

- same for dependencies with `DependencyOverride : ResolverOverride`

> A  class that overrides the value
>   injected whenever there is a
>   dependency of the given type,
>   regardless of where it appears in the
>   object graph.

- same for properties with `PropertyOverride : ResolverOverride`

> A ResolverOverride that lets you override the value for a specified property.

Example

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            var container = new UnityContainer();

            //ParameterOverride example

            container.RegisterType<IConcreteService, ConcreteService>(
                new InjectionConstructor(7) //Old way to pass value to constructor - not flexible. 
                                            //All resolved (without override which appears only in unity 2.0) classes will have val=7
                );

            var service0 = container.Resolve<IConcreteService>();
            Console.WriteLine(service0.Val); //prints 7

            var service = container.Resolve<IConcreteService>(new ParameterOverride("val", 3));
            Console.WriteLine(service.Val); // prints 3

            var service2 = container.Resolve<IConcreteService>(new ParameterOverride("val", 5));
            Console.WriteLine(service2.Val); // prints 5

            Console.ReadLine();

            //DependencyOverride example

            var b0 = container.Resolve<B>(new DependencyOverride<IConcreteService>(new ConcreteService(42)));
            Console.WriteLine(b0.Service.Val); //print 42
            Console.WriteLine(b0.Service1.Val); //print 42

            var b = container.Resolve<B>(new DependencyOverride<IConcreteService>(new ConcreteService(-42)));
            Console.WriteLine(b.Service.Val); // print -42
            Console.WriteLine(b.Service1.Val); // print -42

            Console.ReadLine();

            //PropertyOverride example 

            var b1 = container.Resolve<B>(new PropertyOverride("Service", new ConcreteService(42)), 
                new PropertyOverride("Service1", new ConcreteService(-42)));
            Console.WriteLine(b1.Service.Val); //print 42
            Console.WriteLine(b1.Service1.Val); //print -42

            Console.ReadLine();



        }
    }

    public interface IConcreteService {
        int Val { get; set; }
    }
    public class ConcreteService : IConcreteService {

        public int Val { get; set; }

        public ConcreteService(int val) {
            Val = val;
        }
    }

    public class B {
        [Dependency]
        public IConcreteService Service{ get; set; }

        [Dependency]
        public IConcreteService Service1 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Have no idea why does Google keeps silent about that.

Quotes are from Unity source code xml docs.

Comment: For constructor injection, its still not great. The parameter override will break the moment you rename the constructor parameter.
Ideally, the resolve method should have taken InjectionConstructor

Answer (score 46):

Just in case someone is interested, I have made an extension method that makes the syntax for resolving using `ParameterOverride` a little easier to read. The method is as follows:

```
public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, object parameterOverrides)
    {
        var properties = parameterOverrides
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var overridesArray = properties
            .Select(p => new ParameterOverride(p.Name, p.GetValue(parameterOverrides, null)))
            .Cast<ResolverOverride>()
            .ToArray();
        return container.Resolve<T>(null, overridesArray); //null needed to avoid a StackOverflow :)
    }
}
```

With this, you can rewrite the ParameterOverride example as follows:

```
var service = container.Resolve<IConcreteService>(new {val=3});
```

I hope this is useful for someone...

Comment: The problem with this extension is that it it also overrides the public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, string name, params ResolverOverride[] overrides) extension method, so if you're trying to resolve a type by name with no additional parameters it'll fail. Just need to change the extension name to something else and problem solved, however. :)

Answer (score 15):

Just to add my 2c. You can just add a ParameterOverrides like so:

```
Container.Resolve<IConcreteService>(new ParameterOverrides
{                                                                                   
  {"val", 42}
});
```