# Unity Container resolve with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have a situation where I would like to resolve a class with a dynamic constructor parameter in my ASP.NET 4, MVC web application. I am using Unity v4.0.1. I need the value that is passed to the constructor of the service on Resolve to be be different for each request as shown below.

```
var obj = new MyObject();
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(
          new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), 
          new InjectionConstructor(obj));
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve it as below by taking help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813322/unity-2-0-how-to-use-resolve-with-resolveroverride).

Register my type as

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

In my `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var obj = new MyObject();

    container
        .Resolve<IMyService>(
            new ParameterOverrides
              {
                  {"obj", obj},
              }.OnType<MyService>()
        );
}
```

Make sure to have the constructor of `MyService` as

```
public MyService(MyObject obj){
    //do something here
}
```