# Unity - Why isn't Resolve(ParameterOverride[]) using the expected constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, unity-container

I want to use IoD with a class that implements an interface and has constructors with parameters.

The interface:

```cs
    public interface IUsefulClass
    {
        string InterestingInfo { get; set; }
        string RelevantStuff { get; set; }
    }
```

Two simple properties, nothing much to say about it.

The class:

```cs
    public class UsefulClass : IUsefulClass
    {
        public string InterestingInfo { get; set; }

        public string RelevantStuff { get; set; }

        public UsefulClass()
        {
        }

        public UsefulClass(string p_strInterestingInfo)
        {
            InterestingInfo = p_strInterestingInfo;
        }

        public UsefulClass (string p_strInterestingInfo, string p_strRelevantStuff)
        {
            InterestingInfo = p_strInterestingInfo;
            RelevantStuff = p_strRelevantStuff;
        }
    }
```

It has several different constructors, each setting the properties in its own way.

The call from another class:

```cs
        public void HereGoes()
        {
            IUnityContainer z_ucoContainer = new UnityContainer();

            z_ucoContainer.RegisterType<IUsefulClass, UsefulClass>();

            IUsefulClass z_objUsefulButEmpty = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>();
            IUsefulClass z_objUsefulAndInteresting = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>(new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is interesting information"));
            IUsefulClass z_objUsefulAndInterestingToo = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>(new ParameterOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is very interesting information") });
            IUsefulClass z_objUsefulInterestingAndRelevant = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>(new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is quite interesting information"), new ParameterOverride("p_strRelevantStuff", "More relevant stuff here"));
            IUsefulClass z_objUsefulInterestingAndRelevantAsWell = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>(new ParameterOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is possibly the most interesting information"), new ParameterOverride("p_strRelevantStuff", "Look for relevant stuff there") });
        }
```

On testing and debugging, I find that all five variables have `null` in both properties.

Debugging some more, it turns out that each `Resolve()` calls the parameter-less constructor.

I tried removing said constructor (and the code line that sets `z_objUsefulButEmpty`, naturally): I get a Unity.ResolutionFailedException with the message, "Resolution failed with error: Failed to select a constructor for RegMat_VM.Infrastructure.UsefulClass".

I've looked and looked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820212/9256002) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457486/9256002) among other places), but can't find what I've done wrong. How can I make it work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call like this:

```
IUnityContainer z_ucoContainer = new UnityContainer();
z_ucoContainer.RegisterType<IUsefulClass, UsefulClass>();
z_ucoContainer.RegisterType<IUsefulClass, UsefulClass>("stringConstructor",new InjectionConstructor (typeof(string)));
z_ucoContainer.RegisterType<IUsefulClass, UsefulClass>("string2Constructor", new InjectionConstructor (typeof(string), typeof(string)));
IUsefulClass z_objUsefulButEmpty = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>();
IUsefulClass z_objUsefulAndInteresting = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>("stringConstructor",new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is interesting information"));
IUsefulClass z_objUsefulAndInterestingToo = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>("stringConstructor",new ParameterOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is very interesting information") });
IUsefulClass z_objUsefulInterestingAndRelevant = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>("string2Constructor",new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is quite interesting information"), new ParameterOverride("p_strRelevantStuff", "More relevant stuff here"));
IUsefulClass z_objUsefulInterestingAndRelevantAsWell = z_ucoContainer.Resolve<IUsefulClass>("string2Constructor",new ParameterOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("p_strInterestingInfo", "This is possibly the most interesting information"), new ParameterOverride("p_strRelevantStuff", "Look for relevant stuff there") });
```

This involves knowledge of construction injection.

When there are multiple constructors, you can use `InjectionConstructorAttribute` to decorate the only constructor you need.

When you need to use `multiple constructors` at the **same time**, you need to **name** them and **use that name when parsing**.

For a more general use of named constructors, see below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity;
using Unity.Injection;
using Unity.Resolution;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IPeople, Swordsman>(new InjectionConstructor());//Unnamed default registration, the following default registration will overwrite the previous one
            container.RegisterType<IPeople, Witch>("Witch");//Named registration

            IPeople people=container.Resolve<IPeople>();//Resolve default objects           
            IPeople _witch =container.Resolve<IPeople>("Witch");//Specify the name resolution object

            IEnumerable<IPeople> peoples=container.ResolveAll<IPeople>();//Get all registered named objects of IPeople in the container
            
            people.ClassName = people.GetType().ToString();
            _witch.ClassName = _witch.GetType().ToString();
            var info1= people.ShowInfo();
            var info2= _witch.ShowInfo();

            foreach (var item in peoples)
                {
                item.ClassName = item.GetType().ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(item.ShowInfo());
                }
            Console.WriteLine(info1);
            Console.WriteLine(info2);
            //Dealing with the case of multiple constructors:
            container.RegisterType<IPeople, Swordsman>("SString",new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string)));
            container.RegisterType<IPeople, Swordsman>("TString", new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string), typeof(string)));

            var people2=container.Resolve<IPeople>("SString",new ParameterOverride("o" ,"hello"));
            IPeople people3=container.Resolve<IPeople>("TString",new ParameterOverride ("o", "hello"),new ParameterOverride ("g", "world"));
            Console.WriteLine(people2.ClassName);
            Console.WriteLine(people3.ClassName + people3.ClassAge);
            
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    //People interface
    public interface IPeople {
        string ClassName {
            get; set;
            }
        string ClassAge {
            get; set;
            }
        string ShowInfo ();
        }

    //Witch
    public class Witch : IPeople {
        public string ClassName {
            get; set;
            }
        public string ClassAge {
            get; set;
            }
        public string ShowInfo () {
            return string.Format("Witch:{0}", ClassName);
            }
        }

    //Swordsman 
    public class Swordsman : IPeople {
        public string ClassName {
            get; set;
            }
        public string ClassAge {
            get;set;
            }
        public string ShowInfo () {
            return string.Format("Swordsman:{0}", ClassName);
            }
        
        public Swordsman (string o) {
            ClassName = o;
            }
        //[InjectionConstructor]
        public Swordsman () {
            }
        
        public Swordsman (string o, string g) {
            ClassName = o;
            ClassAge = g;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]