# How to inject into container during runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm using a Unity container to load up my types and wire up my interfaces.

for example:

```
   // type registrations
   container
        .RegisterType(typeof(Startup))
        .RegisterType<IUserProfileHelper, UserProfileHelper>()
        .RegisterType<IUserSecurityManager, UserSecurityManager>()
        .RegisterType(typeof(IDog), typeof(Dog))
        .RegisterType(typeof(ICat), typeof(Cat))
```

However, Cat requires **Meow**:

```
public Class Cat
{
    public Cat(Meow meow)
    {
    }
}
```

Where Meow is a DTO:

```
public class Meow
{
    public int Becibals {get;set;}
    public bool Scratchy {get;set;}
    //etc
}
```

If a client populates the class **Meow** during runtime, how do I inject **Meow** into my container?

If you believe this is a code smell please let me know an alternative pattern to use.

Please note that during runtime, we are outside the scope of when the types are being registered. So perhaps I would need to change the Cat class to not have a constructor at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787001/can-i-pass-constructor-parameters-to-unitys-resolve-method ? Note that without usage sample it is hard to see what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is an anti-pattern. Your [application components should not require runtime data during construction](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Steven well im not talking about construction, i mean i need it during runtime

Comment: Your question states "If a client populates the class Meow during runtime, how do I inject Meow into my container?". In other words, `Meow` is a *runtime* value and you wish to inject it into your `Cat` component. I think my response still applies: don't do this.